# MediaWiki API: Get the category tree

Tags: mediawiki-api

I would like to get the to category tree in JSON format using the MediaWiki API.

For instance, [here is a category named "Story" in the Game of thrones wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Story).

This category have several subcategories, such as [Characters](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters), and this last have also sub categories such as [Major Characters](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Major_Characters).

**Is it possible to have the category tree of all categories of the wiki?**

All the categories [are listed here](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Overview_categories), but:

- this appears to be written by a human (to be confirmed);
- this is an html page, and I would like a JSON result, to simplify parsing and bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have the solution (by using several queries).

From the man page (http://your_wiki.fr/api.php):

- `list=allcategories` returns all the categories of the wiki ;
- `prop=categoryinfo` returns informations about a category, including the number of sub-categories.

We first need to choose the 'root' category where the tree begins. I my case, it is "Story".

Then, by using a generator, we can have, for a given category:

- all its sub-categories,
- the number of sub-categories of each sub-category.

Here with the Game Of Thrones wikia:

http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Story&gcmtype=subcat&gcmlimit=500&prop=categoryinfo

---

Well, now we just need to code a function which returns the subcategories of a category, recursively until there a no sub category:

The first result of query above is:

```
<page pageid="2545" ns="14" title="Category:Characters" touched="2016-06-02T14:20:11Z" lastrevid="92826" counter="" length="67">
    <categoryinfo size="953" pages="935" files="2" subcats="16" />
</page>
```

So subcats>0 ? ok, so lets ask for Characters sub categories:

http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Characters&gcmtype=subcat&gcmlimit=500&prop=categoryinfo|info

etc.